# Can we include a state in existing template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to include an another state template in the existing template.
Do we have anything like ui-include directive which takes state name in src attribute?

Example Code:

```html
<!--Current State Template-->
<p>Current State</P>
<ui-include src="newStateName"></ui-include>
```

Can some one help me on this please.

Why do I need this?

I have three different states performing different operations.
Now I got a scenario where in I need to include all three states in a single state using tabs.
URL should not be updated on clicking of tabs,So I am in need of this to avoid writing more code.

Thanks.

Comment: `<ui-view>` [uiview](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view)

Comment: @CallumLinington So below is the syntax I need to use.
<div ui-view="newStateName"></div>

Correct?

Comment: or `<ui-view name="newStateName"></ui-view>` but why do you need to do this (update your question with the response)

Comment: Updated the question above with more details.

Comment: You can just use a directive, point the controller to your controller and the template to the location of your template... done. That is the easiest way